# Unable to update tracked array in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, array, push

For some reason, the push in the code block below is not updating the array. The console.log statement displays the array with 0 elements. I created a local array variable and pushed to it with no issues, so it seems that problem is pushing to a tracked variable in the LWC. Any thoughts?

```
import { LightningElement, api, track } from 'lwc';

export default class TPM_MS_MaterialSubcontractors extends LightningElement {

    @api matsubs;
    @api display;
    @track countries=[];
    @track addresses = [];

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.getCountries();
        this.getAddresses();
    }

    getAddresses() {
        let addressList = [
            {id: '1', address1: '123 Main Street', address2: 'Suite 100', city: 'Richmond', region: 'Virginia', postalcode: '23835', countrycode: '1'}
        ];

        addressList.forEach(element => {
            let addressString = element.address1 + (element.address2 === '' ? '' : ", " + element.address2) + ', ' + element.city;
            this.addresses.push({id: element.id, address: addressString });
        });
        console.log(this.addresses);
    }

    getCountries() {
        this.countries = [{value: '1', label: 'United States'}, {value: '2', label: 'United Kingdom'}, {value: '3', label: 'India'}];
    }

}
```

Comment: It seems to be working fine atleast in the playgorund. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/gu-ln14M4/6/edit

Answer (score 0):

This problem was resolved by removing the @track annotation.

Comment: That does not seems good. You usually need @track for array and objects if a new property needs to be assigned

Comment: @MohithShrivastava track is no longer always necessary, you'll want to read the release notes.

Comment: @sfdcfox Thank you for comment. Actually you do not need  track for primitive data types but for objects it is good to use because that allows you to maintain reactivity in case properties are assigned values .Check here please (https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring20/release-notes/rn_lwc_track.htm)

Comment: If removing track is a fix to it, i think we should raise a case with support to have lwc framework team confirm it.